# monitor the time taken for each entry in a sql table and notify using email if the time taken is more than 5 minutes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which contains the products details, If it is a new product the status will be 1.

Once it got purchased, the status will change to 2.

My requirement is to send mail to the owner if the product remains in status 1 for more than 5 minutes.

Help me out to proceed further, what are all the ways to do so.

Comment: Simple datecomparison and mail send

Comment: Include on the record the date/time it is created, as well as a flag indicating whether the email has been sent.  Have a periodic job (using any task scheduling system of your choice) which queries the data for a status of 1, a flag of "not sent", and a date/time of more than 5 minutes before the current time.  Send the emails, update the flags.

Comment: Thank you @david !  Can you provide any link for creating such jobs ? the table already contains, datetime coloumn, i will add a Flag for email sent

Comment: You can add a Trigger on the table when a record is being added and then you can do the validation on the status

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add a field like "LastStatusChangedOn", which is a `DateTime` (or a `DateTimeOffset` if you need to keep account with different time zones).

And then just select all Products where the difference between the current time and the `LastStatusChangedOn` is greater than 5 minutes.

Without the exact database structure, it's impossible to give a complete sample, but something like this?

```
SELECT * FROM Products WHERE DateDiff(minute, LastStatusChangeOn, getdate()) > 5
```

Comment: Thank yu so much for your response!! the table alrdy have datetime coloumn, my question is to how to calculate the time taken from the DB side itself.....

Comment: Use the DateDiff function, like in my example.